# Laravel 5.2 auth login working not from the first attempt

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm learning Laravel authentication and created authentication form using command php artisan make:auth. Not changed any line of generated code. Created user test@test.com with password test12 and can't to login at the first attempt. Only in the second or third attempt. 
What I'm doing wrong? 
Thanks.

Comment: When you log out and try again, do you also need to make a second or third attempt? Do you have some errors showing up?

Comment: Yes, after log out I can't to log in from first attempt also. I don't get any errors. Just clear login form.

Comment: I just installed a fresh laravel on Homestead VM and I can't reproduce your problem, which server config are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 5.2.20 on Homestead VM. Do you need config/app.php file or something else?